# Linux text file encoding for open it on Windows

Tags: python, utf-8, character-encoding, text-files, ubuntu-20.04

I have a question between encoding in Linux and Windows. I am saving a text file on linux and dowload it (using Python language) with UTF-8 encoding.

If i open the file with any program in Linux every accent mark o ñ is shown correctly.

When i open the file on Windows in a text editor (like Notepad o Notepad++) it also works fine, but with other programs the accent mark, ñ or other characters are not shown correctly.

Here is my code to open and download file:

```
with open(new_file_path + new_file_temp, 'w+', encoding="utf-8") as f:
           # Writing data

            f.seek(0)
            response = HttpResponse(f.read(), content_type="text/plain; charset=utf-8")
            response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=budget.bc3'
```

bc3 (also know as FIE-BDC) extension is and standard for construction budgets and so on.

So, what do you think the problem is? Problems between unix and windows encodings? Should i save the file with another encoding?

Any help?

EDIT

I'am editing the question adding a minimal reproducible example just saving (without downloading it) the file with accents and "ñ" inside. I am using Django==2.2.5 and Python 3.7.12 in Ubuntu 20.04:

```
import os, random, string
from django.http import HttpResponse

new_file_temp = '/budget.bc3'
new_file_path = os.path.expanduser('~')

with open(new_file_path + new_file_temp, 'w+', encoding="utf-8") as f:
    f.write("~V|Planreforma SL|FIEBDC-3/2020|Stimat||ANSI||2||||\n")
    f.write("~K|3\\3\\3\\8\\3\\3\\3\\3\\EUR|0\\0\\0\\0\\10|8\\3\\3\\3\\3\\3\\3\\3\\3\\3\\3\\3\\EUR\||\n")
    f.write("~C|PRESUPUESTO##||Presu test|522.26|29092021|0|\n")
    f.write("~D|PRESUPUESTO##\n")
    f.write("|C_670483#\\\\1\n")
    f.write("\C_670484#\\\\1\n")
    f.write("\|\n")
    f.write("~C|C_670483#||Albañilería (300 €)|522.00|29092021|0|\n")
    f.write("~D|C_670483#\n")
    f.write("|PC_4694660\\\\1.000\n")
    f.write("\|\n")
    f.write("~C|PC_4694660|u|AYUDAS ALBAÑILERIA|522.00||0|\n")
    f.write("~T|PC_4694660|AYUDAS ALBAÑILERIA PA. en ayuda en cualquier trabajo de albañilería necesario para la correcta ejecución y montaje de las instalaciones , subida y bajadas de materiales, etc. Ayudas albañileria|\n")
    f.write("~C|C_670484#||Máquinas|0.26|29092021|0|\n")
    f.write("~D|C_670484#\n")
    f.write("|PC_4694661\\\\1.000\n")
    f.write("\|\n")
    f.write("~C|PC_4694661|m2|DESB. Y LIMP. TERRENO A MÁQUINA|0.26||0|\n")
    f.write("~T|PC_4694661|M2. Desbroce y limpieza de terreno por medios mecánicos, sin carga ni transporte y con p.p. de costes indirectos.|\n")
    f.write("~M|C_670483#\PC_4694660|1\\1\\|1.000|\n")
    f.write("\ - \\1.000\\\\\\\\|\n")
    f.write("~M|C_670484#\PC_4694661|2\\1\\|1.000|\n")
    f.write("\ - \\1.000\\\\\\\\|\n")
```

I've tried the code above also with "utf-8-sig":

```
with open(new_file_path + new_file_temp, 'w+', encoding="utf-8") as f:
```

So, like i've written above, if i open the file with text editors like gedit, notepad++, notepad, geany, etc the characters are shown correctly (Both Ubuntu and Windows). If i try with programs to open this specific file extension (.bc3) like VisualCost or Presto the problems appears: characters like accents, ñ are not displayed well.

I was looking into and i've tried with Ultraeditor. You can configure this software to tell you if a file is in DOS format or not and this seems to be the problem. The file needs to be in DOS format for mentioned programs (VisualCost and Presto). If i convert it to DOS everything works. So, having in mind that i am generating the file from an UNIX system, what could i do?

Dowload VisualCost (https://itec.es/soporte/descargas/visualcost/)

Download Presto (https://www.rib-software.es/pages/info.htm)

Comment: Some windows applications use a Microsoft version of UTF-8 that prefixes UTF-8 strings with a byte order mark.  In Python this encoding is named "utf-8-sig".  You may find you have to use this encoding for apps like Excel to read files correctly.

Comment: @snakecharmerb and should i set this encode when i open the file or it must be set in every line i write?

Comment: Set it when you open the file.

Comment: @snakecharmerb I've tried, but it doesn't work

Comment: I've fixed it changing encoding and response charset to ISO-8859-1. It's not what i wanted but it solves my problem.

Comment: `ISO-8859-1` only supports a small subset of Unicode characters (256).  Use `utf-8-sig` for *both* writing and reading the file.

Comment: @MarkTolonen I know, but i've tried like you said and it doesn't work. 

`with open(new_file_path + new_file_temp, 'w+', encoding="utf-8-sig") as f:`
`response = HttpResponse(f.read().encode('utf-8-sig'), content_type="text/plain")`

Comment: "It doesn't work" doesn't help.  Edit your question with a [mcve] and specify "other programs" that "don't work".  Demoing reading some undefined variables doesn't help us reproduce the issue.

Comment: @MarkTolonen Sorry about that. I was investigating a little bit more and i've edited my question. I hope everything is more clear.

Answer (score 0):

I found [gauss/fiebdc.py](https://github.com/InigoRd/gauss/blob/master/gbudgets/fiebdc.py) by googling "fiebdc-3 encoding" and it indicates that only the following characters are valid in a .bc3 file, but your file has other accents and a Euro symbol, so it may be violating the specification. See https://www.fiebdc.es/fiebdc (a link from the source header), which also has a downloadable format checker.  It's all in Spanish.  The latest spec is [FIEBDC-3/2020](https://www.fiebdc.es/web2/datos/uploads/Formato-FIEBDC-3-2020.pdf).

```
"valid_code" : re.compile(u"[^A-Za-z0-9ñÑ.$#%&_]"),  # line 105
```

It also indicates the following options for encoding (lines 90-100):

```
self.__format_list = ["FIEBDC-3/95", "FIEBDC-3/98", "FIEBDC-3/2002",
                      "FIEBDC-3/2004", "FIEBDC-3/2007"]
# ANSI->¿"ISO-8859-15" or "latin1 ISO-8859-1" or "cp1252 windows-1252"?
# 850 -> IBM850 -> cp850
# 437 -> IBM437 -> cp437
self.__character_sets_dict = {"ANSI" : "cp1252",
                              "850" : "850",
                              "437" : "cp437"}
self.__file_format = "FIEBDC-3/2007"
self.__generator = globalVars.version
self.__character_set = "850"
```

It seems to imply `850` (`cp850` is an alias), but from your example, only `cp1252` (`Windows-1252` is an alias) supports the Euro symbol.

UTF-8 is not an option.  For your data I would use `cp1252` as it is the only one that supports the Euro symbol.  That's also the default encoding on US and Western European Windows, so seems a likely choice for a Spanish file format if UTF-8 is off the table.

Read the [specification](https://www.fiebdc.es/web2/datos/uploads/Formato-FIEBDC-3-2020.pdf).  I did find a section that specifically mentions using `850` for backward compatibility with older specifications, but it seems a file header can indicate using ANSI (cp1252) if you need the Euro symbol.

Comment: Thanks @Mark Tolonen . I was talking about bc3 especifications with a worker from Presto company and, he's said to me that some rules of bc3 are not completely clear and they use some and o not use others. They work in ther programs with accents and ñ (if you import a bc3 file) but it has to be in DOS format. Yes, i know the page and the file you are mentioning because i've followed these rules to create my file, but documentation is very poor regarding endoding. I will try cp1252. Thank you very much  for your help.

Comment: @Light1988 “DOS format” is ambiguous, both cp850 and cp437 are DOS formats, but for different regions (Western Europe vs. USA). The character mappings differ, but accented characters are the same. The Euro isn’t supported though since it didn’t exist when the encodings were created.